# ValueError: invalid width 0 (must be > 0)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, expect, archlinux

I'm trying to use an expect script in an ArchLinux container docker but I get an error feedback:

```
spawn protonvpn init
[ -- PROTONVPN-CLI INIT -- ]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/protonvpn", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py", line 73, in main
    cli()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py", line 96, in cli
    init_cli()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/protonvpn_cli/cli.py", line 212, in init_cli
    print(textwrap.fill(line, width=term_width))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", line 391, in fill
    return w.fill(text)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", line 363, in fill
    return "\n".join(self.wrap(text))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", line 354, in wrap
    return self._wrap_chunks(chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/textwrap.py", line 248, in _wrap_chunks
    raise ValueError("invalid width %r (must be > 0)" % self.width)
ValueError: invalid width 0 (must be > 0)
send: spawn id exp6 not open
    while executing
"send "$env(ID)\r""
    (file "/sbin/protonvpnActivate.sh" line 5)
```

But when I run it manually in the linux container everything goes well.

```
[root@e2c097bb81ed /]# /usr/bin/expect /sbin/protonvpnActivate.sh

spawn protonvpn init
                                                               [ -- PROTONVPN-CLI INIT -- ]

ProtonVPN uses two different sets of credentials, one for the website and official apps where the username is most likely your e-mail, and one for
connecting to the VPN servers.

You can find the OpenVPN credentials at https://account.protonvpn.com/account.

--- Please make sure to use the OpenVPN credentials ---

Enter your ProtonVPN OpenVPN username: 
Enter your ProtonVPN OpenVPN password: 
Confirm your ProtonVPN OpenVPN password: 

Please choose your ProtonVPN Plan
1) Free
2) Basic
3) Plus
4) Visionary

Your plan: 3

Choose the default OpenVPN protocol.
OpenVPN can act on two different protocols: UDP and TCP.
UDP is preferred for speed but might be blocked in some networks.
TCP is not as fast but a lot harder to block.
Input your preferred protocol. (Default: UDP)

1) UDP
2) TCP

Your choice: 1

You entered the following information:
Username: xxx
Password: xxxxxx
Tier: Plus
Default protocol: UDP

Is this information correct? [Y/n]: Y
Writing configuration to disk...

Done! Your account has been successfully initialized.
```

Here is the lauching script whitch use expect command:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn protonvpn init
expect "username:"
send "$env(ID)\r"
expect "password:"
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
expect "password:"
send "$env(PASSWORD)\r"
expect "plan:"
send "3\r"
expect "choice:"
send "1\r"
expect "correct?"
send "Y\r"
expect eof
```

And here is the docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3.7"
services:
     protonvpn:
       image: protonvpn:archlinux_template
       environment:
         - ID=***
         - PASSWORD=******
       volumes:
         - "/opt/protonvpn/entrypoint.sh:/sbin/entrypoint.sh:rw"
         - "/opt/protonvpn/protonvpnActivate.sh:/sbin/protonvpnActivate.sh:rw"
       entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
       cap_add:
         - NET_ADMIN
       devices:
         - /dev/net/tun
       stdin_open: true
       privileged: true
       restart: unless-stopped
```

In advance, thank you for all the help you can provide.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the script is trying to read the terminal width, but the terminal width is 0. Maybe try adding `tty: true` to the docker-compose, like so:

```
version: "3.7"
services:
     protonvpn:
       image: protonvpn:archlinux_template
       environment:
         - ID=***
         - PASSWORD=******
       volumes:
         - "/opt/protonvpn/entrypoint.sh:/sbin/entrypoint.sh:rw"
         - "/opt/protonvpn/protonvpnActivate.sh:/sbin/protonvpnActivate.sh:rw"
       entrypoint: ["/bin/bash", "/sbin/entrypoint.sh"]
       cap_add:
         - NET_ADMIN
       devices:
         - /dev/net/tun
       stdin_open: true
       tty: true
       privileged: true
       restart: unless-stopped
```

There is also an old docker bug that might be related: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/33794

If that's the issue would edit your environment section to be the following:

```
environment:
    - COLUMNS=`tput cols`
    - LINES=`tput lines`
    - ID=***
    - PASSWORD=******
```

Comment: Ok i tried adding environment and TTY but no change

Comment: ok, you might want to go through some of those tips in the docker issue I linked, lots of them manually resize the terminal, you could likely add that to your script

Comment: Works for me, thanks !